# Random LI selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have 3 li's with all a data-panename.
I want a random li to be selected every refresh.

How to make a javascript/jQuery script to make a random `data-panename` get the class `active`?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tab-tabs">
 <li class="first" data-panename="uitgelicht"><a href="/nl?show=Uitgelicht" rel="nofollow">Uitgelicht</a></li>
 <li data-panename="nieuw"><a href="/nl?show=Nieuw" rel="nofollow">Nieuw</a></li>
 <li class="last" data-panename="meest-bekeken"><a href="/nl?show=Meest+bekeken" rel="nofollow">Meest bekeken</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var lis = $('li[data-panename]');
lis.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*lis.length)).addClass('active');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jCPva/) (reload to see a different li in red)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$lis = $('.tab-tabs li');

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*$lis.length);

$lis.eq(randomIndex).addClass('active;);
```

EDIT: `Math.round()` co-domain was too wide of course.

Comment: after alot of refreshes only the first 2 are getting selected.

Comment: Math.round isn't what should be used. See my answer.

Comment: @dystroy yeah, I can get out of bounds this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
**JS**

```
​$(document)​.ready(function() {
    var selector = '.tab-tabs > li:eq('+Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+')';
    $(selector).addClass('active');
});​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    background-color:#FFAA00;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B6ywm/